# Can't install Mint, failed to create drive

Tags: linux-mint, partition, system-installation, partition-table

I have been trying to install Linux for almost two weeks now. Tried it with Ubuntu and Mint (I prefer Mint, but the errors are the same).

error:

`The creation of swap space in partions #w of SCS1 (0, 1, 0) 
(sdb) failed.`

I have tried many different installation methods but they all seem to result in the same error. I have documented my last try [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmDHM.jpg)

-edit:

`sudo gdisk -1 /dev/sdb` returns: `GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1`

-edit2:

after making a `bios_grub` label on sdb (minimal size is 7mb, i also created a swap drive)

`sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb` returns: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x12nh.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question and show `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Comment: Welcome to U&L ,are you trying to install linux-mint without a swap partition, it can be replaced by a swap file later?

Comment: @GAD3R yes, tried that. Then it failed on an other drive

Comment: From your bios settings , choose the Legacy boot then make the `sdb` drive on the first boot ordre, Create a small partition `1M` on `sdb` , flag it `bios_grub` to allow installing grub on the GPT drive

Comment: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb` this -l is a little L not number 1.  There was a windows on the disk before? Or in use with windows. As data drive? Partition type basic data is windows stuff.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition

Comment: i created a `bios_grub` flag on my drive, set my bios to accept legacy and booted from the drive. It then [failed to boot](http://imgur.com/a/NyVan).

There was never a windows instalation in that ssd. I bought it new and only used it for linux, when mint failed to install i tried creating a NTFS drive and installed some games on it to test if the drive was working and that worked out fine.

Comment: Switch back to uefi. Save data if necessary from the harddrive. In windows wipe the hole disk. Be careful which disk you choose. I mean partitions and partitions table. So the harddrive is "virgin".   You have other hd's in your computer. Any windows on them?  Boot Mint `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Went back to UEFI, wiped the drive (couldn’t destroy the table). I have one hdd with windows and a few for data, but I unplugged them when going into Linux. `sudo parted -l` returns: [this](http://imgur.com/a/TRnnZ), I also tried installing mint again and it wrote some stuff on the [syslog](https://mega.nz/#!SZN22DjT!0ldFalxwPcwukPGr8CHKw3XY80iH5Xptrb627YuMIXg), maybe its useful.

Comment: Hello? Can you guys help me further?